# ajax upload file after choose file auto submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I tried to make ajax upload and I don't wanna make a submit button. just let user when choose file done auto submit..

I tried use `change()` to get form data change but after click second time it will alert not just once. I don't know why , is there any better idea to make it work!

HTML

```
<div class="article-create">
    <table class="table">
        <td>
            <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <input type="file" name="image" class="browseimage">
            </form>
            <li class="browseimage-fake btn btn-success btn-sm">Choose File</li>
```

js

```
$('.article-create .table').on('click', '.browseimage-fake', function() {
    $(this).closest('td').find('.browseimage').click();

    $(this).closest('td').find('.browseimage').change(function(){
        alert('change');

        // check FormData and ajax ..
    });
});
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to submit the form and upload the file as soon as it is selected. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes this is what I want! but I'm stuck in   trigger alert too much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Alert calls just one time:

```
$(document).on('change', '.browseimage', function(){
    alert('change');
    // check FormData and ajax ..
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9mPw/20/

Comment: `$('.article-create .table').on('click', '.browseimage-fake', function() {  $(this).closest('td').find('.browseimage').click();$(this).closest('td').on('change', '.browseimage', function() {
    alert('change');
   });
  });`

Comment: it still alert not just one time??

Comment: user1575921, in your code you call an internal function twice, thats why you have 2 alerts

Comment: Sorry I can't get it..  the first function make if click fakebutton it will fire real button to choose file ,  and second is detect form change..

Comment: I hope it help you to fix your problem and explain what do I mean

Comment: wow!! thanks! so if the `article-create`  `btowseimage` is new dom from append. I just change the `bind` to `on` then it will be ok, right?

Answer (score 0):

simple JQUERY change function.

```
$(".browseimage-fake").change(function() {
console.log("changed")
});
```

Comment: this is what i did in my question!  my problem is  it will console.log not just one time with my code

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me but only when I had a valid url for the `action` attribute of the `form`.

```
<script>
    $(".browseimage").change(function () {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    });
</script>
```